# How does Common Language Infrastructure work and what is its purpose?

Tags: java, c#, c++-cli

As a Java programmer, the concept of CLI seems unclear to me. Does developing a C# application imply that the exact same binary executable only has to be compiled once and can then be executed on Windows if .NET framework is installed and on Linux with Mono installed? If so, how does that work?

Comment: Couple of links obtainet by googling .net CLR http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bs2ecf4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The biggest difference between Java (the platform) and CLI is that the JVM is primarily targeted by Java, but C# is just one of the .Net languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

When we compile our code an assembly will be created. This assembly can be loaded later to the CLR that will compile the MSIL code, that exists in the files of the assembly in native code and our application will start.

The CLI you refer to is the intermediate language in which your code written in C# or another .net language will be compiled to by the corresponding compiler. Furthermore is the language that CLR "understands" and can compile it to native code.

Also, an assembly is not binary executable. It can have two forms either an executable or a dll. Either of them are collection of files that defines the types that your application etc.

So as a bottom line CLI has only one purpose.

**update**

> So the assembly you mention is roughly equivalent to the Bytecode in
>   java, which gets JIT-compiled at runtime and is platform-independent?

As it is stated in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language):

> Common Intermediate Language (CIL, pronounced either "sil" or "kil")
>   (formerly called Microsoft Intermediate Language or MSIL) is the
>   lowest-level human-readable programming language defined by the Common
>   Language Infrastructure (CLI) specification and is used by the .NET
>   Framework and Mono. Languages which target a CLI-compatible runtime
>   environment compile to CIL, which is assembled into an object code
>   that has a bytecode-style format. CIL is an object-oriented assembly
>   language, and is entirely stack-based. Its bytecode is translated into
>   native code or — most commonly — executed by a virtual machine.

A nice detailed read of the above and many more related to them is the first chapter (The CLR's execution model) of [CLR via C#, by Jeffrey Richter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667454).

Comment: So the assembly you mention is roughly equivalent to the Bytecode in java, which gets JIT-compiled at runtime and is platform-independent?

Answer (score 1):

CLI is .Net analog of JVM.
Mono does not support all of the libraries that Windows has.

Comment: This is more suitable as a comment.

Comment: The CLR would be the equivalent of the JVM.

Comment: It's a fair answer given the Java comparison in the question.